# What are the exact setups to observe a wave function and its collapsed state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wave-particle-duality, wavefunction-collapse

I was reading this article: http://io9.com/5528321/how-smart-do-you-need-to-be-to-collapse-a-wave-function and I need some clarification on the experiment setup.

My current understanding is that if we are not focused on trying to figure out which slit the particle went through, the wave pattern is there. So where is the camera placed?

Otherwise, as the article says, if the cameras are placed on top of the slits or after the slits (I presume that is between the slits and the wall), the wave function collapses.

Comment: If your question is "Where is the camera placed?", then the answer, of course, is that cameras are placed wherever people choose to place them.  What did you really mean to ask?

Comment: @WillO I hope no one will answer so erroneously. In the context, it can mean to place it above the whole setup, behind the wall or before the slit or whatever. But what was the exact placement that have let scientists observe the wave function without collapsing it?

Comment: I have no idea what it means to "observe a wave function", but if it means anything at all, it's surely impossible.  All you can ever observe is a single eigenvalue of a single observable.

Comment: Perhaps it means to observe an interference pattern on the back screen when it's a wave function, or just two bars when the function collapses due to observation.

Comment: To observe an interference pattern on the back screen, one looks at the back screen.  If you insist on involving a camera, you can place the camera anywhere you like, take a picture of the back screen, and look at the picture.

Comment: Please don't confuse my question further. It is not about where I place the camera. The question is about _where did the scientist place their measuring/observation devices_.